# $a\geq 0$, $x\sim y$ implies $x+a\sim y+a$ so the preference is linear?

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, preferences

$\succsim$ is a countinuous and convex weak order.

$x,y,a$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^n$

We say $a\geq0$ if all directions of the vector $a$ is greater or equal to zero.

We want to prove (or disprove by counterexample) that:

Suppose $x\sim y$ implies $x+a\sim y+a$ for any $a\geq0$ and $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$,

Then the preference is linear.

---

One definition of linear preference is that $x\sim y$ implies $x+a\sim y+a$ for any $x,y,a$.

Comment: Should be $x\sim y$ in the title I guess.

Comment: @VARulle Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.

Let $n=1$ and define $u(x)=\min{\{x,0\}}$. Let $\succsim$ be the preference relation represented by $u$. This preference relation is continuous and convex. We also have $x\sim y$ implies $x+a\sim y+a$ for any $a\geq0$ and $x,y\in\mathbb R$. But let $x=0$, $y=1$, and $a=-1$. Then $x\sim y$, but $y+a=0\succ -1=x+a$, thus $x+a\nsim y+a$ and $\succsim$ is not linear.

Comment: This is a good answer! However, in economics, most if not utility functions are strictly increasing. It would be very helpful if you could give me a hint on how to obtain a counterexample that is also strictly increasing in both elements.

Comment: @HighGPA: Well, that's a whole new thing, and I guess linearity would then indeed follow. Try posting this as a new question.

Comment: I believe so. I posted that altered question on the Math forum. Do you believe that I could post it on the Econ forum again? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591086/forall-a0-fx-fy-leftrightarrow-fxa-fya-implies-forall-b-f/3592171#3592171

Comment: @HighGPA: If you frame it as a question on monotone, continuous, convex preferences on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it belongs to economic theory, I'd say.

Comment: Hi, I post a new question and it seems like that I find a proof. Do you mind to check it?https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/35670/a-geq-0-x-succsim-y-implies-xa-succsim-ya-so-the-preference-is-linear